# How to suppress Python syntax warning highlighting in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have an import that is being done via git clone, and adding to the path, but Python is saying its not known.

https://i.imgur.com/EepL6fc.png

I found something that looked like it might work, but it doesn't.

```
import mcfee  # pyright ignore[reportMissingImport]
```

Also tried:

```
# pylint: disable-next==reportMissingImport
import mcfee  # pylint: disable=reportMissingImport
```

Is there anyway to suppress this kind of slightly annoying warning in Colab?

Thanks in advance,
Winton